# Automatic generation of header file in VisualStudio

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am porting a C project in VisualSudio 2017 (from a make-based project) and I am facing a problem. One of the headers (let's say "a.h") is generated by a script whose input is a CSV file. I am able to launch the script by adding the CSV file to the project sources, setting a custom build rule on it and specifying "a.h" as output.
The problem is that VisualStudio doesn't seem to see the dependency between "a.h" and the C sources where it's included. E.g. when I issue a "rebuild all" "a.h" is deleted and the C sources are compiled first, so I get a "#include file not found" error. Tried to add the C sources in Custom build's Ouptput, but this way a "Rebuild" deletes them too. Please note that another similar case works perfectly, the only difference is that the output file is a C souce (e.g. "b.c") instead of a C header.
As a last chance, I added to the solution a separate project whose output is "a.h", and specified a dependency between projects to force the correct compilation sequence.
I would prefer not to have a separate project. Is there a way to force a dependency between a C source and a .h generated "on the fly"?

Comment: It is a really long time since I dealt with MS VS, but I believe there should be something like "pre-build" and "post-build" steps in the project settings.

Comment: Correct, but they don't do exactly what I need (although it's a good approximation). I would like to avoid the generation of a.h if CSV file is older, but when a.h needs to be rebuilt, C files should be compiled too.